# Password change failed because password does not meet minimum quality requirements. What does this error mean?

Tags: passwd

On my **macOS** machine, I tried something like:

```bsh
passwd derp
```

After I input the old password and the new password, it shows the following:

```
passwd: Password change failed because password does not meet minimum quality requirements.  Password change failed because password does not meet minimum quality requirements.
```

I am using a company computer that is connected to an external authentication directory.

What does this error mean? Also, how can I show the criteria/minimum quality requirements?

Comment: You should precise what you have. On Debian, the password complexity requirements are in /etc/pam.d/common-password in RedHat, in /etc/security/pwquality.conf. 

You should indicates also if your system is connected to an external authentication directory (Active Directory…).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer I edited the question for your suggestions.

Comment: @terdon I edited the question for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you give the output of `pwpolicy getaccountpolicies` ?

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer There was a 2-line output. Line #1: `Getting global account policies`

Line #2: `Error: The daemon encountered an error processing request.`